# How to use bfast function on daily stock prices?

Tags: r, time-series

I wish to find the structural breaks in the time series of daily (closing price) stock stock prices. I was considering using `bfast package` for this. bfast requires the input variable to be a `ts` object. Most examples I found for ts use monthly data which gives a nice frequncy of 12. But for daily data, that won't be the case and there will be missing data on holidays.

Any idea on how to make this work on an xts object or if any other package helps here?

Comment: Converting to `zoo` will solve your problem.

Comment: @Metrics I don't think bfast accepts zoo objects.